# Show Unnecessary "0" inputs

Tags: iphone, xcode, zero, decimalformat

I am building a calculator and have run into a problem with displaying unnecessary 0's (it isn't displaying them and I want it to be).

An example of what it does now is as follows. [Represents Calculator Screen]

[Blank Calculator Screen]

User hits "4"

[4]

User hits "."

[4]

User hits "0"

[4]

User hits "0"

[4]

User hits "5"

[4.005]

**Instead, I want to make it do the following:**

[Blank Calculator Screen]

User hits "4"

[4]

User hits "."

[4.]

User hits "0"

[4.0]

User hits "0"

[4.00]

User hits "5"

[4.005]

I use a number formatter as shown below...

```
 formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
     formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 13;
     formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
     formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 13;
     formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 13;
     formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
     formatter.groupingSeparator = @",";
     formatter.decimalSeparator = @".";
     formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true;
```

I use the following to call my numbers...

```
 buttonScreen.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:
 [NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentNumber]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference ?  [4.005] vs. [4.005]

Comment: When typing it out, it doesn't look right if it jumps from 4 to 4.005 on the screen, particularly when there are more 0's (4 to 4.000000008 compared to showing the addition of each 0 when it is keyed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not giving you the zeroes because 4 is the exact floating point representation of 4, 4.0, 4.00, etc. I suggest that you store the user input into a `NSString *`, which you then convert into an `NSNumber` when you need to do actual math.

Answer (score 0):

You could get around this issue by not evaluating the input before "=" or an operation key is pressed.

You would just add to the string and transform the string into the correct number once the entry is finished which you know because a different key has been pressed.